# Setting the FieldOffset of a pointer to a structure to the same value as a fixed byte array

Tags: c#, pointers, layout, struct, fixed

i am new to stackoverflow and i would have a question about C# structs and their layout.

Let's assume following structs:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public unsafe struct Link
{
    // some primitive data (2 integers for example)
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Pack = 1)]
public unsafe struct Node
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public int LinkCount;
    [FieldOffset(4)]
    public Link* Links;
    [FieldOffset(4)]
    private fixed byte _linksData[10 * sizeof(Link)];
}
```

The reason for that is that i need a blittable type for IO-Performance.
I have to deal with very large (and sparse a maximum of 10 links per node) graphs which have several GB in size.
The graph is represented as an array of Node-structs.
With the setup like above i was hoping of being able to read for example a hundred MB from the graph file into a byte-pointer (which of course points to a byte-buffer) and cast it to a pointer of type Node* which yields very good performance.
At first my Node-struct just had 10 separate variables of type Link (Link0, ..., Link10) which worked just fine. But it would be nice to make this configurable at compile-time, which lead to the above Node-struct.

I was hoping, that Links would just point to the same memory location as _linksData since it has the same FieldOffset.
But actually the Links pointer always is a null pointer.

So my question is:
Is there a way that Links points to the same memory location as _linksData or is there another way to have a fixed sized array of structs embedded into another struct.

Thanks for every answer in advance - Markus

After reading Ben Voigt's post I tryed something similar without the need of changing the struct to a class. The following is how it works for me:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Pack = 1)]
public unsafe struct Node
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public int LinkCount;
    [FieldOffset(4)]
    private fixed byte _linksData[10 * sizeof(Link)];

    public Link* GetLinks()
    {
       fixed(byte* pLinksData = _linksData)
       {
          return (Link*)pLinksData;
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: That last snippet is going to get you in deep trouble.  The pointer is only valid inside the fixed block.  Once you get out, the returned pointer is going to dangle to wherever the struct is stored.  And there are no good places in .NET where that comes to a good end, neither the stack nor the gc heap.  Unless you explicitly marshal the structure to unmanaged memory.

Comment: @Hans: I think Markus is smart enough not to use the pointer after the object goes away, which is good enough for stack variables.  For members of class instances, however, there is indeed a problem, and I mentioned this also.

Comment: @Hans Uhhh - thanks I actually missed that. But in my real project I would anyways only return one Link like Ben showed in his example.

Comment: @Ben Thanks for thinking of me being smart enough ^^ but I really forgot that even with the fixed byte-array the whole struct could be moved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that you're not actually trying to store a pointer, just have a correctly-typed way to access the 10 elements.  How about:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Pack = 1)]
public unsafe struct Node
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public int LinkCount;
    [FieldOffset(4)]
    private fixed byte _linksData[10 * sizeof(Link)];

    public Link* Links { get { return _linksData; } };
}
```

No, wait, .NET supports interior pointers but C# doesn't, so that won't work.  You can only have a pointer into a .NET object if you've pinned it or placed it on the stack, and we don't know if that's the case here.

:(

Full-on wrapper time:

```
public class LinkCollection
{
    Node peer;
    public LinkCollection(Node node) { peer = node; }
    void CheckIndex(int index) { if (index < 0 || index >= 10) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(); }
    public Link default[int index] {
        get { CheckIndex(index); return peer.GetLink(index); }
        set { CheckIndex(index); peer.SetLink(index, value); }
    }
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Pack = 1)]
public unsafe class Node
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public int LinkCount;
    [FieldOffset(4)]
    private fixed byte _linksData[10 * sizeof(Link)];

    unsafe Link GetLink(int index) { fixed( Link* plink = (Link*)&_linksData[0] ) return plink[index]; }
    unsafe void SetLink(int index, Link newvalue) { fixed( Link* plink = (Link*)&linksData[0] ) plink[index] = newvalue; }
    public LinkCollection Links { get { return new LinkCollection(this); } };
}
```

Note that I had to change `Node` to a class... p/invoke should still act pretty much the same though.

If you don't want to do that, extension methods might be an answer.

Comment: Hi - also thanks for the answer (I can't believe how fast this works around here). This approach gives the message, that fixed sized buffers only work on primitive types as the ones mentioned by Alois.

Comment: @Markus: What he said is that you need a blitable type, which this is.  The restriction to primitive types, excluding structures of primitive types, is crazy.  I think I see a workaround... no actually not.  No interior pointer support in C#.

Comment: Your idea with the property actually made me test something, which works. I'll post it within the next minutes. Changing it to a class is not possible in my case because I need value types.

Comment: I just inserted the code in my original post which I have now in my own project and which is working. Thanks for the idea - that made it work :) so i marked your answer as the accepted answer.

Comment: @Markus: Unfortunately, that's dangerous.  You're using the pointer outside the fixed block, which means that the object might have been moved by the garbage collection in between.

Answer (score 0):

You can only marshal blitable types. This restricts you to instances of IntPtr, string, byte,char int,  float, double, decimal and the unsigned counterparts. You cannot define pointers to other data constructs you are also interested in. This is currently not supported.

The Marhsaler needs to know how much space the final instance will take and it needs to know when to stop. When you define a pointer to a managed type it would need to marshal the pointer also before you can access it because as it is now a managed type you get always a copy back. These problems are solvable to some extent but as far as I know this is currently not supported. Perhaps .NET 4.5 brings some new features.

**Edit1:**

To get something out of your structure you can leave the pointer as IntPtr and simply use an extension method to do the heavy lifting (marshalling) by yourself. I do not know if the original Links are pinned or not. This assumes that the Links are not movable (either unmanaged data or pinned managed objects).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;


unsafe class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Link[] arr = new Link[] { 
            new Link(1),
            new Link(2),
            new Link(3),
            new Link(4),
        };

        fixed (Link* pLinks = arr) // for demo purposes create a node instance
        {
            var nde = new Node
            {
                LinkCount = arr.Length,
                Links = new IntPtr(pLinks) // Marshal as IntPtr is safe, later the data can be retrieved via an Extension method.
            };

            foreach (var link in nde.GetLinks())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Link {0}", link.I);
            }
        };
    }
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public unsafe struct Link
{
    // some primitive data (2 integers for example)
    public int I;

    public Link(int i)
    {
        I = i;
    }
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Pack = 1)]
public unsafe struct Node
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public int LinkCount;
    [FieldOffset(4)]
    public IntPtr Links; // this assumes that the Links is some unsafe buffer which is not under GC control or it is pinned
}


static class LinkExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<Link> GetLinks(this Node node)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < node.LinkCount; i++) // very efficient if you want to traverse millions of nodes without marshalling all of them at once
        {
            // alternatively you can also use a memcpy (PInvoke to msvcrt.dll) to fill in the data from a given offset.
            // it is up to you to decide which is faster
            yield return (Link)Marshal.PtrToStructure(node.Links + IntPtr.Size * i, typeof(Link));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi - thanks for the (really fast) answer. But actually I already defined a pointer like fixed(Node* pNodes = NodesArray) where NodesArray is of type Node[] and i casted it to a byte pointer which was then used in the native FileWrite method. Or is this a completely different case?